# How to retain tag casing when using document.createElement()?

Tags: javascript, svg, createelement

I need to dynamically insert some tags into the `<filter>` element of an `<svg>`.  The tags in question have camelCased tag name, and also use some attributes with camelCased names.

When I use `document.createElement('feDiffuseLighting')` I would expect the created element to be `<feDiffuseLighting>` but instead it is created as ``` - all lower case.

Normally I would think that this wouldn't matter, however it actually seems to matter!  See my example below. Inspect the elements and you'll see they are identical except for casing. In the dev tools if you right click and select "Edit as HTML" and manually change the casing to camelCase, you'll see the SVG appear as expected.

How can I get `document.createElement` to respect thecasing I defined? Or is there some other way to create an element with the proper casing?

```js
const diffuseLightingEl = document.createElement('feDiffuseLighting');
diffuseLightingEl.setAttribute('in', 'noise2');
diffuseLightingEl.setAttribute('lighting-color', '#ffffff');
diffuseLightingEl.setAttribute('surfaceScale', '2');

const distantLightEl = document.createElement('feDistantLight');
distantLightEl.setAttribute('azimuth', '45');
distantLightEl.setAttribute('elevation', '60');

diffuseLightingEl.appendChild(distantLightEl);
document.querySelector('#noise-filter2').appendChild(diffuseLightingEl)
```

```css
body{height: 100vh;margin:0; display:flex; align-items:stretch; gap:1rem;}
body div{flex:1;}
svg{height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div>
  <strong>Element Manually Added</strong>
  <svg>
    <filter id="noise-filter1">
      <feTurbulence stitchTiles="stitch" result="noise1" baseFrequency="0.519" numOctaves="5" type="fractalNoise" seed="0"></feTurbulence>
      <feDiffuseLighting in="noise1" lighting-color="#ffffff" surfaceScale="2">
        <feDistantLight azimuth="45" elevation="60"></feDistantLight>
      </feDiffuseLighting>
    </filter>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#noise-filter1)" fill="none"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <strong>Element Dynamically Added</strong>
  <svg>
    <filter id="noise-filter2">
       <feTurbulence stitchTiles="stitch" result="noise2" baseFrequency="0.519" numOctaves="5" type="fractalNoise" seed="0"></feTurbulence>
    </filter>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#noise-filter2)" fill="none"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not about creating lowercase tag names, but XML-compliant elements. And that means you must use `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feDiffuseLighting")`. SVG has its own namespace, and that must be named explicitely **for each element created**. That you will see then case-sensitivity is a side effect of XML rules being applied, not HTML rules.

Comment: Wow, I learned something new. I had no idea.  That absolutely works, thanks!  If you make that an answer I will mark is correct